# Multiple instances of same access database are open on 1 machine - problem

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, scheduled-tasks

I'm having issues with a ms access 2007 accdb, using Windows Server 2008 task scheduler for scheduled tasks.  The problem is the file that's being opened by the task scheduler is opening/closing properly, but the 'lock' file (.laccdb) remains visible after the database is closed, which is an indicator that the access db thinks it's still open.  Each time a new task runs, a new instance of access is being opened.  I opened the Schema to show roster of all users in the database and it's showing 3 duplicates of the server name/Admin account.  Below is an example of the immediate window in access:

COMPUTER_NAME    LOGIN_NAME    CONNECTED   SUSPECT_STATE
SERVER           Admin         True        Null
SERVER           Admin         True        Null
SERVER           Admin         True        Null

I'm hoping someone else has had this problem and knows 1) How to easily close all the open instances of access and 2) how to prevent this from occuring when running a task.  I have "Do not start a new instance" set under the task's 'settings' tab, but this is irrelevant b/c none of the tasks were running simultaneously.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What is the task that you're running? Chances are it's not properly cleaning up, or not exiting correctly. But we can't guess until we know what the task is. It could also be a permissions issue (i.e., DELETE permission is denied on the folder where the database is), but that's very unlikely, as it's non-standard permissions that have to be set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

To close all open Access instances (you can't run this from Access because you can't guarantee that the running instance will be the last reference you retrieve):

```
Sub CloseAllAccessInstances()
    Dim acc As Access.Application

    Do
        Set acc = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

        If IsNull(acc) Then Exit Do

        acc.Quit
    Loop
End Sub
```

After you run the above, check the task manager.  If you see msaccess.exe, then you most likely have a circular object reference.  This will prevent Access from closing.  For more information, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716190(VS.60).aspx.

Comment: This is inadvisable, in my opinion, as it could conceivably corrupt a data file if you force quit Access when a record is locked for editing.

Comment: Access.Application.Quit() forces nothing.  It's the same as closing the application through the user interface, so the application will clean up before it quits.  Furthermore, the optional AcQuitOption argument gives you a little bit of control over how the application handles that clean up (specifically, how it handles unsaved objects).